# firefox search bar defaults to i'm feeling lucky?

Tags: firefox, search

In Firefox, I'd like the search bar to default to Google's "I'm Feeling Lucky" search (thereby skipping the search results page). Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Head to the [Google section of the Mycroft Project](http://mycroft.mozdev.org/google-search-plugins.html) and then just click on the "I'm Feeling Lucky" version to have it install into your browser.

This also works for IE7/8 and any other browser which supports the OpenSearch format.

Answer (score 9):

You can default the search to 'I'm feeling lucky' by adding

```
&btnI=745
```

to the url for the search.

So in Firefox, go to about:config
and change the value for keyword.URL from

```
http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=navclient&gfns=1&q=
```

to

```
http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=navclient&gfns=1&btnI=745&q=
```

**Update**: Apparently the change above is for keyword search, not for the search bar in the upper right.
For that to change, you have to change the **`google.xml`** file located in

```
<yourFirefoxInstallFolder>\searchplugins
```

and add a rule

```
<Param name="btnI" value="745"/>
```

so the whole file looks like this:

```
<SearchPlugin xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/2006/browser/search/">
<ShortName>Google</ShortName>
<Description>Google Search</Description>
<InputEncoding>UTF-8</InputEncoding>
<Image width="16" height="16">data:image/x-icon;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAIAAACQkWg2AAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAaRJREFUeNpiVIg5JRURw0A0YAHio943kYV%2B%2Ff33%2BdvvX7%2F%2FMjEx8nKycrGzwKXOiPKzICvdeezLhCV3jp15%2Bfv%2FX0YGhv8MDDxMX2qKTIw0RK10eYD6QYqATvoPBkt3f5K0W9Ew4fjTFz%2F%2Bw8Dm3W8UPeZxqFa%2BevsFyD0twgfVsOfkRxHrtfV9u5BVQ8Crd98%2FffkGYQM1QJ20%2FfSPv79eNxQGYfpSVJADmcvEAHbr7oOX2dj%2FERNKIA2%2F%2F%2Fz%2FxfCDhYVoDUDw5P6vf9%2B5iY0HVmZGQWm%2BN3fff%2Fn2k4eLHS739x%2FDiRs%2Ff%2F%2F5x8HO%2FOHzN3djfqgNjIwMgc6qzLx%2Fpy47j2zY%2Feff06tXhOUucgxeun33AUZGpHh4%2Bvo7t8EyIJqz%2FhpasD59%2B5dNrqdnznZIsEL9ICXCsWuBCwvTv%2FymS5PWPP32ExEALz%2F%2BB5r848cPCJcRaMP9xaYQzofPPzfuvrnj0Jst%2B5%2F8%2Bc4sLPeDkYlRgJc93VPE18NIXkYUmJYQSQMZ%2FP3379uPH7%2F%2F%2FEETBzqJ0WqLGvFpe2LCC4AAAwAyjg7ENzDDWAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg%3D%3D</Image>
<Url type="application/x-suggestions+json" method="GET" template="http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=firefox&amp;client=firefox&amp;hl={moz:locale}&amp;q={searchTerms}"/>
<Url type="text/html" method="GET" template="http://www.google.com/search">
  <Param name="q" value="{searchTerms}"/>
  <Param name="ie" value="utf-8"/>
  <Param name="oe" value="utf-8"/>
  <Param name="aq" value="t"/>
  <Param name="btnI" value="745"/>
  <!-- Dynamic parameters -->
  <Param name="rls" value="{moz:distributionID}:{moz:locale}:{moz:official}"/>
  <MozParam name="client" condition="defaultEngine" trueValue="firefox-a" falseValue="firefox"/>
</Url>
<SearchForm>http://www.google.com/firefox</SearchForm>
</SearchPlugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can tweak the config file, by following these instructions : http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/location%20bar%20search

Comment: Would you add some content from the linked article?